# configure error: GNU gettext tools not found; required for intltool

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, gimp, apt-get

I am using Linux for the first 2 days. I am doing my best to learn the terminal commands etc.

I am currently trying to install Gimp. After doing `./configure` it gives me this error:

```
configure: error: GNU gettext tools not found; required for intltool
```

For past hours I was installing this `intltool`, because it was old version.

I have tried to:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install
apt-get install gettext
```

Unfortunately it shows me message that it couldn't find packages.

What do I do now?

I am using Kali Linux, as I know its based on Debian so I tagged it too.

Comment: You're trying to build GIMP from source. If you are the same user who did show up on irc.gimp.org some days ago with Kali: there were some people who did advise against Kali. From the Wikipedia article: "Kali Linux is a Debian-derived Linux distribution designed for digital forensics and penetration testing." - so no, it is not your general-purpose Linux distribution for running all kinds of software.

Comment: But debian is, i hoped that if its based on debian, it will have all its features. Thank you for your answer